# Rails Association clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I am looking to confirm whether the following association declaration's would work of if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

I have a Animal Model and where you can create a dog, cat, rabbit etc, I also need to specify what breed the animal is, so i thought set up a model for each animal breed type, so DogBreed for example and then Cat Breed.

I was thinking that each animal can only have one breed, so would something like this work

```
 class Animal
   has_one :dog_breed
   has_one :cat_breed
 end

class DogBreed
  belongs_to :animal
end

class CatBreed
  belongs_to :animal
end
```

Colums for each model would be

```
Animal
  name
  description
  size
  breed

DogBreed
  name

CatBreed
  name
```

is there a better way to approach this?

Also i will be adding accepts_nested_attributes_for to the animal model for each breed model

Thanks

Comment: +1 for your continued persistence with Rails!

Comment: Writing answer for you

Comment: What other columns do you have on each of the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STI**

You're looking for [`Single Table Inheritance`](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance):

```
#app/models/animal.rb
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :x
end

#app/models/dog.rb
class Dog < Animal
end

#app/models/cat.rb
class Cat < Animal
end
```

As the name "Single Table Inheritance" suggests, your "dependent" models will *inherit* from. This means you will be able to store a central table called `animals`, into which **you'll need to add a `type` column**:

> $ rails g migration AddTypeToAnimals

```
#db/migrate/add_type_to_animals.rb
class AddTypeToAnimals
   def change
      add_column :animals, :type, :string
   end
end
```

--

**Fix**

The way this works is actually very simple.

You can call your `Dog` and `Cat` models with impunity (no changes out of the scope of "normal" Rails work). The `type` column will be populated automatically:

```
#app/controllers/dogs_controller.b
class DogsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @owner_dog = Dog.new
   end

   def create
      @owner_dog = Dog.new dog_params
      @owner_dog.save
   end

   private

   def dog_params
      params.require(:dog).permit(:x,:y,:z)
   end
end
```

---

**Update**

From our Skype talk, you'll probably want to do this:

```
#app/models/animal.rb
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | breed_id | name | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :breed
   delegate :name, to: :breed, prefix: true
end

#app/models/breed.rb
class Breed < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | name | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :animals
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/animals_controller.rb
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
   def new 
      @animal = Animal.new
   end

   def create 
      @animal = Animal.new animal_params
   end

   private

   def animal_params
      params.require(:animal).permit(:name, :breed_id)
   end
end

#app/views/animals/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @animal do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.collection_select :breed_id, Breed.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: With the updated question your solution then just needs to have a `breed` string type on animal rather than an association presumably set via a select that's populated with options from the appropriate model.

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want to achieve, so i can use accepts_nested_attributes_for with a belongs_to relationship coming from the animal_breed models ?

Comment: Yes, I think I addressed this with the update. Although a simpler solution, I believe it's what you need given the new context you provided